# 自然対数の割り算の意味がわからない

Tags: javascript

Byte サイズから適切なサイズ名（KB、MBなど）を算出するコードの中で、
`Math.log()` を使用しているものを見つけたのですが、これはどういう意味でしょうか。

```
function formatBytes(fileSize) {
  const i = Math.floor(Math.log(fileSize) / Math.log(1024))
  return `${Math.round(fileSize / (1024 ** i))}${['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'][i]}`
}
```

自然対数[^1](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log) にしている意味と、それを割ることで index が出せる理由がわかりません。

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ある数値ｘがあって`log(x)/log(1024)`することの意味はｘが１０２４の何乗かを求めていることになります。

累乗数と対数の関係が
y = a<sup>x</sup> の時 x = log<sub>a</sub> y
で
この場合累乗数ｘは
x = log<sub>1024</sub> y で、
底の変換をすると、（底はｅ（つまり自然対数）でも１０（常用対数）でもなんでも構いません）
log<sub>1024</sub> y = log<sub>e</sub> y / log<sub>e</sub> 1024
となります。
つまりファイルサイズが１０２４の何乗かを求めていることになります。
それで、端数を切り捨てると
ちょうど１０２４の０乗・１乗・２乗・・の整数の累乗数となって
配列`['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB']`のインデックスとして使えます。